# python format datetime with “st”, “nd”, “rd”, “th” I want to convert group of files with format 2ndFeb_proxy_

Tags: iphone

I want to extract date from group of filenames with format 2ndFeb_proxy_. Using regular expression i parsed it to 2ndFeb then how to convert this to date. Here 2nd is becoming a problem.

Comment: have you got your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get using like this

```
NSString *str = @"2ndFeb_proxy_";

    NSString *dayString;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];

    // Collect numbers.
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&dayString];

    NSLog(@"Day %@",dayString);
```

**Output : Day 2**

And then convert this day to NSDate format.And i hope you wanna like this.

Comment: Welcome dear and Have you got your solution then accept this answer.